# Cartier operator and trace

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$. Let $X$ be a smooth projective $d$-dimensional variety over $k$. Let $F\colon X\to X'$ be the relative frobenius morphism.

There is a Cartier operator for all $i$, $$C^{-1}\colon \Omega^i_{X'/k}\to F_*\Omega^i_{X/k},$$ induced by $\mathrm{d}(a\otimes 1)\mapsto a^{p-1}\mathrm{d}a$.

There exists a trace map given by Grothendieck duality $\mathrm{Tr}\colon RF_*F^!\mathcal{G}\to\mathcal{G}$. Here note that $F^!\mathcal{G}$ is defined by $\mathcal{G}\otimes\Omega^d_{X/k}\otimes(\Omega^d_{X'/k})^{\otimes-1}$.
If we take $\mathcal{G}=\Omega^d_{X'/k}$, the trace gives a map $$\mathrm{Tr}\colon F_*\Omega_{X/k}^d\to \Omega^d_{X'/k}.$$

Question: Why are $C^{-1}$ and $\mathrm{Tr}$ mutually inverse? (It is not clear how the trace map is defined..) [This is mentioned in Deligne-Illusie "Relevements modulo $p^2$ et decomposition du complexe de de Rham" P.255]

Comment: The target of $C^{-1}$ should be $\mathcal{H}^i(F_* \Omega^\bullet_{X/k})$, the $i$-th cohomology sheaf of the de Rham complex.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this comparison is done very explicitly in chapter 1.2 of the book by Brion and Kumar on Frobenius splittings.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Thanks! I replaced "Cartier isomorphism" by "Cartier operator".

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I found something related in 1.3 of the book, let me check if I understand it, thanks for the reference!